# Logger on Xcode console

Tags: ios, swift, macos

## Overview:

- I am logging some messages using `Logger`
- I would like these messages to be printed on to Xcode without the timestamp and other details
- I want only the message to be displayed

## Questions:

1. How can I display only the message on the Xcode console (see preferred output)?
2. Is there a setting in Xcode to remove the timestamp prefix?
3. Is there an alternate approach?

## Note:

- I need to use `Logger` because this app would be released, so print is not an option.

## Example Code

```
import SwiftUI
import os

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let logger = Logger(subsystem: "MyApp", category: "MyCategory")
    let itemName = "something non-sensitive"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .onAppear {
                logger.debug("content view displayed")
                logger.debug("Item name = \(itemName, privacy: .public)")
            }
    }
}
```

## Actual Output:

```
2022-11-25 18:41:10.116408+0800 Demo[36175:5518724] [MyCategory] content view displayed
```

## Preferred Output:

One of the following would be ideal:

```
content view displayed
```

```
Demo[36175:5518724] [MyCategory] content view displayed
```

### My failed attempt

```
#if DEBUG
struct Logger {
    
    let subsystem: String
    let category: String
    
    func debug(_ message: String) {
        print(message)
    }
    
    //This will not help:
//    func debug(_ message: OSLogMessage) {
//        print(message)
//    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Can you just use `print`?

Comment: @JeremyP IMHO The problem with print is that it is slow on released prod app. Logger is great except while debugging on Xcode there is a lot of noise (with timestamp)

Comment: @JeremyP Based on your comment I tried to use print for Debug, but didn't know how to build it, see my "My Failed Attempt" section in my question

Comment: I know you wrote Xcode inside the question title but wouldn't console app fit your needs? There you can set which fields you want to observe

Comment: @dziobaczy I find Xcode a little more convenient without having to switch between console. And on the console need to stream and stop